# Updating rotating banner on e-commerce homepage

Tags: upgrade, products, delete, banner-slider

I have Two questions:

1) I am trying to update the images of my e-Commerce rotating banner homepage. I went to the developer’s page, uploaded a new image, enabled it, and disabled the previous demo ones. It didn’t help on the live site.

2) I want to delete a few products from my e-commerce. I selected the products in my catalog and went to Action —> delete items. But I can still seem them on the live site.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

Add new image and delete previous images after use this command and check it.

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex

php bin/magento cache:clean
```